# compiz-config-profile-setter crashed with SIGABRT in cssObjectGetInterface

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz

I'm running

- Ubuntu 16.04
- compiz 0.9.12.3
- unity 7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubutu1

I have 0 packages to update.

I have an empty screen. The background colour is correct, but the rest of the UI has not loaded. I can open a terminal and then run programmes such as firefox, but I can't change the window sizes or summon their menus by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>. The top bar with the time, internet connection status, etc. is not visible. I can't see the Ubuntu equivalent of the start menu.

Basically unity is not running.

When I log in I get a crash report regarding `compiz-config-profile-setter` with the error message as in the title. The screen was as I described above. I ran `apt-get upgrade` but unity is still broken.

I tried running `compiz --replace` but  nothing changed.

Has anyone encountered this? How can I fix it?

Comment: That did not fix it for me.

Comment: In the end I updated to 18.04. That cleared up this issue, but left me with a bunch of others

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR:

Try this: In `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config`, change `profile = unity-lowgfx` to `profile = unity` and reboot.

(Tested on **Ubuntu 16.04** LTS)

---

1. Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Find `config` file in `compizconfig` directory somewhere in your home directory. (In my case, the path was `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config`)
3. Edit this file with your favourite editor (like *vim* or *gedit*)

```sh
gedit .config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
```

4. You should find there something like:

```
[general_ubuntu]
profile = unity-lowgfx
```

Change `unity-lowgfx` to `unity` so it looks like this:

```
[general_ubuntu]
profile = unity
```

5. Save changes and reboot Ubuntu (try `reboot` in command line)

Solution source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1758009/comments/5

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by removing compiz settings directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.compiz/compiz-1/
```